# Server error when I try to log on sitecore desktop

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

Trying to resolve this since long time. Though i know that there mismatch in the control type, i couldn't resolve. Can anyone help on this?

The base class includes the field 'FailureText2', but its type (Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Literal) is not compatible with the type of control (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal).

```
Line 136: </asp:Login>
Line 137: <div id="LoginText">
Line 138: <asp:Literal ID="FailureText2" runat="server" />
Line 139: </div>
Line 140: <div id="LoginOptions">
```

I'm using sitecore 6.4

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a Web App or a Website in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this problem a bunch of times. I recommend getting the zip file of the base install from the Sitecore Developer Network and copying the entirety of the "Website/bin" directory into the bin directory of your web root.

In addition to that, make sure any Sitecore dlls that you're using in your solution are set to "Copy Local = false".

Comment: I had given a try to upgrade my sitecore from 6.4 to 6.5 some days before. Though i had given similar try it did not work for me earlier since some how, some dlls were not reverted back. I replaced sitecore and bin folders under webroot. Going reverse from here, i had take out some custom configurations as well. Thank you so much for you help dhulk

Answer (score 2):

I would venture to guess that your .designer file has the control confused. Look in your `[controlname].designer.cs` file. Locate the line that says:

```
protected global::Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Literal FailureText2;
```

and replace it with

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal FailureText2;
```

If that isn't the case you will need to post up some more code.

Comment: Sean Kearny, Thanks for the reply. I didnt have designer.cs file for this. Probable fix for the problem is below. Thanks for your time and effort to help me out.

Comment: not below, at the top. I have marked it as the answer for question

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have resolved the issue by this time. I had similar issue when upgraded from 6.4 to  6.5. Sitecore have replaced text items in table layout with their own custom controls (Label), So page appears broken.

They have added custom namespace to register their controls. Which is logical thing to do, as they can have more control over the rendering and other business.

```
    <%@ Register Assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" 
Namespace="Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls" TagPrefix="sc" %>
```

For example,  `Password:` literal are replaced with `<sc:Literal runat="server" Text="Password:" />`

This might be taken care by upgrade process, but in my case, when I upgrade to 6.5 on developer machine, these files were locked by TFS. The solution was to download clean 6.5 zip containing site and compare with local version.

I had replaced lot of files on my Dev version and all is working fine now. I hope this will be useful to someone, someday.